# how do I split ISCSICLI list targets for two different targets

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2, iscsi

In PowerShell im trying to use the split command on some text from `ISCSICLI list targets` and connect to that target using the `ISCSIcli QLoginTarget` command. Here is the script I have to do that thus far:

```bsh
iscsicli listtargets t
$target = ISCSICLI listtargets
$test = $target | Out-String
$test1, $test2 = $test.Split(":", 2)
$t1 = $test2.Trim()
$T1 = $T1.TrimEnd('The operation completed successfully.')
$T1 = $t1.Substring(0, $T1.Length - 2)
ISCSIcli QLoginTarget $T1
```

This script works very well when there is only 1 target available to the server. As soon as I have more than 1 target on the Windows 2008 R2 server the variable at the end of the script has two different IQN's for `$T1`. See image:

[image: T1 Variable output]

Does anyone know how to split the `$t1` variable into two different IQN's using the split command? I would like to connect to two of these presented iSCSI targets by splitting this variable but I'm not sure how to do so.

Comment: `$iqn1,$iqn2 = $t1 -split '\s+'`

Comment: It looks like that worked! Thanks very much :). What does the '\s+' do ?